# How to clear shared memory using php?

Tags: php, shared-memory

I want to ask about why after I use shmop_delete($shmid) and shmop_close($shmid) there is nothing happen? the first string is still attaced.

This is my php code:
    $key = 864;
    $mode = 'c';
    $permission = 0644;
    $size = 1024;

```
$shmid = shmop_open($key, $mode, $permission, 1024);

$string = "Hello World !!!";

shmop_write($shmid, $string, 0);

$size = shmop_size($shmid);
echo shmop_read($shmid, 0, $size);

shmop_delete($shmid);
shmop_close($shmid);
```

First Result: **Hello World !!!**

Then I change $string = "TEST".

After that I run the code again with result : **TESTo World !!!** (Unwanted Result).
The result I want is : **TEST**

why the 'o World !!!' is still attached although I already did shmop_delete and shmop_close? And How I can erase it from Shared Memory? Thx...

Answer (score 0):

When you first write "Hello World" it's writing the length of those 11 chars.  When "Test" is written, it only writes the length of "Test" into the shared memory.  That is why the rest of the string is still attached.  One potential solution is to take the length written like so:

$shm_bytes_written = shmop_write($shmid, $string, 0);

and pad the next string to that length.  Or I guess you could write the entire size of the shared block, but that's probably not what you want.

Edit:

The code should be something like this (not tested nor compiled).  This is for ASCII.  If you're using UTF-8, you'll need to handle getting the string length a bit differently.  Hopefully you get the idea

```
$shmid = shmop_open($key, $mode, $permission, 1024);

$string = "Hello World !!!";

$s1bytes = strlen( $string );

$shm_bytes_written = shmop_write($shmid, $string, 0);

$string2 = "Test";

$padLen = strlen( $string ) - strlen( $string2 );

$s2Pad = str_pad( "Test", $padLen );

$shm_bytes_written = shmop_write($shmid, $s2Pad, 0);

$size = shmop_size($shmid);
echo shmop_read($shmid, 0, $size);

shmop_delete($shmid);
shmop_close($shmid);
```

Comment: actually what I want to do is to overwrite the first string in shared memory with second string. But the problem is how to overwrite first string in shared memory with second string if the first string length is longer than second string length? How to overwrite it without left any trace from first string. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution from [php.net shmop_read's comment by Craig Manley](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shmop-read.php)

demo code, 'hello' overwrite 'helloworld':

```
$shmid = shmop_open(10014, "c", 0755, 2048);
$size = shmop_size($shmid);
$write = "helloworld";
$writeStr = str_to_nts($write);
shmop_write($shmid,$writeStr, 0);
$str = shmop_read($shmid, 0, $size);
$rawStr =  str_from_mem($str);
$oldLengh = mb_strlen($rawStr, '8bit');
echo $rawStr . "\n";
echo $oldLengh . "\n";

$writeStr = "hello";
shmop_write($shmid, str_to_nts($writeStr), 0);
$str = shmop_read($shmid, 0, $size);
$rawStr =  str_from_mem($str);
$newLengh = mb_strlen($rawStr, '8bit');
echo $rawStr . "\n";
echo $newLengh . "\n";
shmop_delete($shmid);
shmop_close($shmid);
```

definition:

```
function str_from_mem(&$value) {
    $i = strpos($value, "\0");
    if ($i === false) {
        return $value;
    }
    $result =  substr($value, 0, $i);
    return $result;
}
function str_to_nts($value) {
    return "$value\0";
}
```

And as Craig Manley's comment: shmop_read() reads and returns the whole memory segment's data. This is not useful if you're just working with strings.

Comment: but this solution still "left any trace from first string".However, your can get correct strings by '\0' ending.

Answer (score 0):

I’m new to `shmop`, and I couldn’t find anything about this either. I found a simple solution which works for me, starting with your own code:

```php
$key = 864; $mode = 'c'; $permission = 0644; $size = 1024;
$shmid = shmop_open($key, $mode, $permission, $size);

$string = 'lengthy';
$string = str_pad($string,$size,"\0");
shmop_write($shmid,$string,0);

$string = 'short';
$string = str_pad($string,$size,"\0");
shmop_write($shmid,$string,0);

$string = shmop_read($shmid,0,0);
$string = rtrim($string);
print $string;
```

OK, it’s a bit stretched out, but the trick is to use `str_pad($string,$size,"\0")` to zero-fill the string, so you can trim the result after reading.

If you really just want to clear out the string, you could try:

```php
$string = str_repeat("\0",$size);
shmop_write($shmid,$string,0);
```